# Add Progress Bar in Tab Host on WebView

Tags: android

Hello
Well i'm very basic in java , here is my java code about my activity class, i can't add progress bar in webview , please help me in my code
Here My Java Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;
//Set Activity Irancell:
public class Irancell extends Activity {
WebView Irancell_Charge;
//Start App Code at here:
@Override
// Set iCicle:
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);
//Load Irancel Buy Creadit Page:
Irancell_Charge=new WebView(this);
setContentView(Irancell_Charge);
Irancell_Charge.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
Irancell_Charge.loadUrl("http://www.echarge.ir/Templates/irancellshop/m/");
//Text Label:
Toast
.makeText(this, "MTN Irancell Recharge Cards...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
.show();
}
}
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the progression with an animated progress bar you have to implement these codes:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will show a spinner when the page is navigating. Every time the user navigates to a new page, a loader / progress will appear.

I use a WebViewClient to achieve this.

```
package sherif.android.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebClientTestActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog mSpinner;
    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //initialise your spinner
        mSpinner = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mSpinner.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mSpinner.setMessage("Loading..."); 
        //initialise your webview
        webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://sherifandroid.blogspot.com/");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new SherifWebClient());
        setContentView(webView);
    }
    private class SherifWebClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            mSpinner.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mSpinner.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```